# JupyterLab output doesnt show visualization

Tags: spacy, kaggle, jupyter-lab

Encountered this issue with 2 different visualization libraries. 
PYLDAVIS  and DISPLACY (spacy). 
On executing a code in jupyterlab (kernel as python3), the output expected should be Jupyter Notebook to show the graph or webcontent. But my Jupyter doesnt show any output with graph / dependency image . I only see textual output in JupyterLab.

eg.

```
displacy.serve(doc, style='dep')
```

I'm using KAGGLE docker image which has JUPYTERLAB and on top of that I have updated  to latest packages.

Any pointers if this is JUPYTERLAB related or underlying packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only really comment on the spaCy part of this, but one thing I noticed is that you are using `displacy.serve` instead of `displacy.render`, which would be the correct method to call from within a Jupyter environment ([see the spaCy visualizer docs](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#section-jupyter) for a full example and more details). The reason behind this is that `displacy.serve` will start a web server to show the visualization in a browser – all of which is not necessary if you're already in a Jupyter Notebook. So when you call `displacy.render`, it will detect your Jupyter environment, and wrap the visualization accordingly. You can also set `jupyter=True` to force this behaviour.

Comment: Awesome, able to see now.  Without the jupyter=True i could see the output widget was showing SVG tags in html format.

Comment: I was going thru the documents https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#ent and then realized further down in the documentation is   https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#jupyter. We are good here.

Comment: Side issue - i see a warning message on displacy.render

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py:193: DeprecationWarning: Positional arguments to Doc.merge are deprecated. Instead, use the keyword arguments, for example tag=, lemma= or ent_type=.

Comment: Thanks – I'm one of the spaCy maintainers btw so I just fixed this on `master`. Looks like displaCy was still using the old and now deprecated way of calling `Doc.merge`.

Comment: Just setting `displacy.render(doc, jupyter=True)` worked fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
from spacy import displacy
displacy.render(doc, style="dep", jupyter=True, options={'distance': 140})
```

or

```
displacy.render(doc, style="ent", jupyter=True, options={'distance': 140})
```